# Objeto firebase sempre retornando undefined fora da subscribe

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, firebase

Estou tentando fazer algo simples, é um aplicativo de venda de roupas, e estou na parte das devoluções. Ocorre que eu preciso obter a quantidade de estoque daquele item, naquele determinado momento para então fazer a devolução e a alimentação do estoque de forma correta. Já montei todo o algoritmo, porém estou com uma dificuldade para enviar um update ao meu nó de produtos do firebase.

1º Sempre que tento mostrar o valor do objeto fora da subscribe, ele me retorna undefined.

2º Eu não consigo trabalhar com nenhuma propriedade dele fora da subscribe, então não consigo realizar a soma das quantidades de devolução e estoque.

3º Funciona apenas se eu fizer o update dentro da subscribe, mas isso me retorna um loop infinito, chega travar o meu navegador, agora não sei como proceder neste caso.

Meu código é super simples:

```
  devolverItem(item: any){
   let pathItens = `/itens/`;
   this.itensFirebase = this.db.list(pathItens, {
     query: {
     orderByChild: 'key',
     equalTo: item.key
   }
  });

  this.itensFirebase.subscribe( data => {
     this.itemEstoqueSemGrade = data;
  })

  //Aqui ele me retorna sempre o undefined
  console.log(this.itemEstoqueSemGrade);
 }
```

Este é um exemplo de como "funciona", porém com o loop:

```
  devolverItem(item: any){
   let pathItens = `/itens/`;
   this.itensFirebase = this.db.list(pathItens, {
     query: {
       orderByChild: 'key',
       equalTo: item.key
     }
   });

   this.itensFirebase.subscribe( data => {
     this.itemEstoqueSemGrade = data;
     this.quantidadeItemAtualizarEstoqueTotal = 
     this.itemEstoqueSemGrade[0].quantidade + item.quantidadeDevolver;
     this.db.object(`/itens/${item.key}/`).update({
        quantidade: this.quantidadeItemAtualizarEstoqueTotal
     })
   })

 }
```

Essa segunda opção ao meu ver não faz o menor sentido, entendo que eu teria que fazer isso fora dali, mas se tento trabalhar com os dados do meu itemEstoqueSemGrade fora dali, ele me retorna sempre undefined, então não consigo realizar nenhuma operação.

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda..

Comment: Diego, Melhorei o código colocando um exemplo com seu código, só depois que havia publicado vi que você estava usando o AngularFire e melhorei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite amigo,

Vamos a explicação técnica primeiro, esse Código seu é Assincrono, e algumas coisas estão acontecendo em uma ordem diferente do que está escrito, você está fazendo uso de Observables nesse caso através do método Subscribe, ou seja, o seu primeiro prolema é que o console.log() está rodando antes do conteúdo do subscribe.

Quando você executa o método Subscribe, você passa um function como parâmetro, essa function está sendo inscrita em um Observable, e não executada imediatamente,  a fila do Observable é quem vai executar esse código 1 ou mais vezes.

O seu segundo problema é esse "mais vezes" que disse anteriormente, o comando .update() atualiza os dados no firebase, e como essa conexão é realtime, a function que você passou no subscribe roda novamente, e novamente, e entra no loop infinito que você identificou.

Para resolver seu problema você precisa usar os métodos Once do firebase, que não ficam conectados em tempo real, mas que retorna a lista uma vez e não fica acompanhando mudanças, para você poder fazer a atualização.

olha um exemplo com seu código (não testado)

```js
 devolverItem(item: any){
   let pathItens = `/itens/`;
   this.itensFirebase = this.db.database.ref(pathItens)
   .orderByKey()
   .equalTo(item.key);

   this.itensFirebase.once('value', data => {
      this.itemEstoqueSemGrade = data;
   });

  //Aqui ele me retorna sempre o undefined
  // aqui sempre vai retorna Undefined porque roda antes do observable
  console.log(this.itemEstoqueSemGrade);
 }
```

Mesmo nesse exemplo você vai perceber um "encadeamento" de código, parecido com o que você colocou no seu segundo código, e isso é normal, como eu disse, a function que está sendo inscrita pelo método Subscribe vai ser executada de forma assinrona, já que existe um tempo de espera pelos dados, o mesmo acontece pra essa function que estou passando dentro do .then(), neste caso, diferente do subscribe, que mantem uma conexão em tempo real (seu update disparava o método de novo), o .then() vai ser executado apenas uma vez quando a lista estiver retornado, em termos técnicos quando a Promisse estiver Resolvida.

Segue o link para o doc do Realtime Database, se você estiver usando o Firebase Firestore vai encontrar a documentação no mesmo site, procumer o método .once

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?hl=pt-br